# What is the proper interpretation of REST when GETting by different identifiers?

Tags: rest

I'm building a REST API and I want to have the purest interpretation of the URI for  accessing resources using multiple unique identifiers.  For example, my underlying POCO looks like this:

```
public class Account
{
  int AccountId { get; set; }
  string Mnemonic { get; set; }
  string LegacyId { get; set; }
  string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The primary key is AccountId and is intended primarily as an internal identifier (also to be used by the UX), but the mnemonic is unique as well and intended for humans to use (and for importing from external systems).  There may also be a legacy system identifier hanging around from an older system.  When accessing an element by the primary key, there's no question that the URI should be:

```
GET: http://myserver/api/account/123
```

But how should we access the records using the other unique identifiers?  I've seen the query form used:

```
GET: http://myserver/api/account?query=EmergingMarkets
```

This strikes me as inherently non-REST in that it looks like an action rather than a reference.  I've been using this form:

```
GET: http://myserver/api/account/mnemonic/EmergingMarkets
GET: http://myserver/api/account/legacyId/EM10
```

Which is the better interpretation of pure REST.  Is there another option not listed above?

Comment: Applications following the REST architecture design shouldn't care how a URI looks like. The URI as a whole is just a pointer which when invoked should return some representation of a resources state. The URI shouldn't be interpreted but meaningful link-relation names used instead to determine whether to invoke the URI or not. You might define a link-relation names such as `mnemonic`, `name` or `id` though the meaning need to be specifed somewhere so a client can make use of it actually

Answer (score 1):

I'll second Roman from the comments. There's a few different interpretations of REST, but when specifically talking about 'purest', generally I think you need to look in the direction of HATEOAS / Hypermedia service, per the original definition.

That definition is pretty loose, because it doesn't state an *exact* contract of how a binding with HTTP should look like, but generally it's accepted that the URIs should be discovered by following links, instead of through out-of-band information. Clients shouldn't have to really hardcode URI patterns, and there's several mechanisms that aid specifically with searches (such as HAL templated links).

So those paragraphs answer your questioin by the letter, lets now answer what you probably want to know: what is an elegant URI design for your specific problem that's predictable and sane from an API design perspective.

First thing I would ask is, why do you need the 'id' form at all?

```
 http://myserver/api/account/123
```

`123` is kind of ugly key and kind of meaningless if you don't directly access the database. It sounds like there's a 1:1 relationship with your "mnemonic" why not ditch the numeric form altogether and always use the natural key.

It looks a lot nicer, and removes the duplication problem in one go. If that's not an option (maybe not every entity has a "mnemonic"), and you must have 2 places to access a resource, I think:

`?query=x` suggest to me that this is a search that can return 0 to `n` resources as a collection. I would personally avoid this for singular, unique resources. It's not an *action*, the *action* is still `GET` so for search it would have been fine.

That leaves `/api/account/mnemonic/EmergingMarkets`, although personally I would put it in a different namespace as `/api/account`. Since `api/account` looks like a collection that has all the accounts as members, `api/account/mnemomic` might *look* like an another account. It speaks more to my sensibilities that there are 2 distinct structures, such as:

```
/api/account/id/123
/api/account/mnenomic/EmergingMarkets
```

Or:

```
/api/account/123
/api/account-by-mnenomic/EmergingMarkets
```

Anyway, the first part of my answer was what you asked and fact-based, the second part is the answer I *think* you want, but obviously completely opinion-driven. Ask 5 more people and you might at least get a few different answers.

**Bonus**

If you do have 2 of the same resources hosted at 2 different urls, there's a few different ways to tell clients they are really the same thing:

1. Have 1 do a permanent redirect (`308`) to the other.
2. Serve your document on both, and use a `canonical` link to indicate there's a canonical place to fetch the information.
3. Use `Content-Location` header to do the same.

Comment: >> "It sounds like there's a 1:1 relationship with your "mnemonic" why not ditch the numeric form altogether and always use the natural key".  Because (1) there is an underlying database, (2) you don't join on strings and (3) the real world has many different ways to identify objects.  An accounting system may have one 'mnemonic' for an account, and a settlement system may have another.  UX that can query will likely use the integer.  It's SOP to normalize to a key inside a web service.

Comment: Not sure why you would suddenly have to join on strings if you ditch 1 of the 2 URI patterns. Aside from that, don't forget that the web itself is built on the idea of using strings for identifying relationsips + there are many examples of large-scale popular APIs that successfully avoid numeric database ids. Exposing id's in this manner It's a leaky abstraction and not SOP. It might be a requirement for you specifically though, just don't call it standard.

Comment: Anyway, the only reason I brought it up is because it's the best option _if it's possible_. If not, I left some other suggestions.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts.  I think you have a well-reasoned argument for the pattern */api/account/id/123* and */api/account/mnemonic/EmergingMarkets*.  I also like the Bonus material and think it may have some use as we are talking about the same underlying resource.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont need to expose the id form http://myserver/api/account/123 and the every account has a unique mnemonic, the form http://myserver/api/account/ would be perfectly valid as you are using the mnemonic as the identifier. Nothing about REST dictates that the primary key of the database must be the identifier your service exposes. Anything that uniquely identifies a resource can be used.

Comment: I'm afraid I didn't describe the problem adequately, then.  The 'mnemonic' many be one of several external identifiers.  An accounting system may provide a 'mnemonic', a settlement system may use a 'ShortName', there may be a legacy system around with 'OldAccountId'.  When building a web service, it's not unusual to concentrate data from multiple sources, each with their own concept of 'identifier'.  All of these address the same account (resource) inside the web service.

Comment: Is each mnemonic guaranteed unique across the system? In order words, does a mnemonic identify exactly one record in the database, even if other mnemonics identify the same record? If so, I go back to the notion that REST does not describe a system that forces the use of the primary key of the database record. Any identifier which uniquely identifies 1 and only 1 record can be used this way. This is part of the point of an API, it abstracts underlying implementation details and presents a well defined structure for a consumer.

Comment: Yes, I got the part about the 1-to-1 relation.  The question remains, what's the best (i.e. most RESTful) way to address the resource with multiple unique identifiers?

Comment: "Best" is very subjective. It depends a lot on your system/implementation and API consumers.

Comment: That is possibly the most useless bit of advice I've seen on this board.  I specifically called out "most RESTful".  I do not subscribe to your "REST can be anything you want it to be" philosophy.